# How to order ActiveRecord query based on calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'd like to list bakeries by the number pastries they have on sale, say.

To rank them, I would sum the multiplication of the number of pastries available of each pastry, by the percentage they are on sale. Bakery could have 0-10 pastries on sale. For example:

```
bakery1.pastry1 = 100
bakery1.pastry1_discount = 10 (%)
bakery1.pastry2 = 50
bakery1.pastry2_discount = 20 (%)
(2 pastries on sale)
```

(100 x 10) + (50 x 20) = 2000 .. would be listed first

```
bakery2.pastry1 = 10
bakery2.pastry1_discount = 40
bakery2.pastry2 = nil
bakery2.pastry2_discount = nil
(only 1 pastry on sale, etc)
```

10 x 40 = 400 .. listed 2nd

```
bakery3.pastry1 = 10
bakery3.pastry1_discount = 20
bakery3.pastry2 = nil
bakery3.pastry2_discount = nil
```

10 x 20 = 200 .. listed last

So how do I order Bakery by the sum of the multiplication of certain attribute values?

I understand thus far that sort_by is heavy on the memory of the database.

UPDATE:  ... it'd have to be (pastries available - pastries sold) x discount

Comment: Bakery 1 has 100 pastries available and 10 on sale?

Comment: I understand the conceptual problem (ordering by a calculated value in associated records) but your example doesn’t seem to make much sense :)

Comment: @Scooter, I've updated the question - bakery1 has 100 pastries available at 10% discount. Essentially I need a way to rank Bakery, so I multiply the amount of pastries they make available at a discount, by the percentage they are on discount to acquire points. The higher the points, the higher their rank. But then I don't know how to order Bakery by their points

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem. Here is the solution to this,

```
class Bakery
  attr_accessor :name, :pastries

  def initialize(name, pastries)
    @name = name
    @pastries = pastries
  end

  def order_value
    pastries.sum { |_, values| values[:pastry].nil? ? 0 : values[:pastry] * values[:discount] }
  end

  def self.order(*bakeries)
    bakeries.max_by(&:order_value)
  end
end
```

## Example

```
bakery1 = Bakery.new("Bakery1", { pastry1: { pastry: 100, discount: 10 },pastry2: { pastry: 50, discount: 20 } })
bakery2 = Bakery.new("Bakery2", { pastry1: { pastry: 10, discount: 40 } })
bakery3 = Bakery.new("Bakery3", { pastry1: { pastry: 10, discount: 20 } })

highest_order_bakery = Bakery.order(bakery1, bakery2, bakery3)

puts "#{highest_order_bakery.name}: #{highest_order_bakery.order_value} order value"

highest_order_bakery.pastries.sort_by { |_, values| -values[:discount] }.each do |pastry, values|
 puts "  #{pastry}: #{values[:discount]}% discount"
end
```

Comment: The question is about the [`order`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) method in ActiveRecord, not about a custom implementation.

Comment: @daveasdf_2 I assumed you wanted to order on the database side because your title says _"How to order ActiveRecord query ..."_.

Comment: ... or any way to order instances by multiplying the values of attributes

Comment: @Stefan, yes thank you, looking to order/sort/rank instances in controller before sending to view, by summing the multiplication of specific attributes

Answer (score 0):

i will use `sort_by` instead of `order` and made an instance method to calculate available pastries

```rb
class Bakery
 # method to calculate pastery availability
 def pastery_count
   count = 0
   self.pastery.each do |ps|
     count = count + ps.count.to_i * ps.discount.to_i
   end

   count
 end
end
```

then call with `sort_by`

```rb
Bakery.sort_by{|br| br.pastery_count}
```

you can also combine with `where` clause

```rb
Bakery.where(...).sort_by{|br| br.pastery_count}
```

Comment: `Bakery.sort_by` – where does that class method come from?

Comment: @WALVISK thank you.  [max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712000/22518297) suggests order, due to server memory issues with sort_by. Would it work the same way with the same syntax with order?

Comment: you are right, it load all data to memory but i can't find a way using `order` . @daveasdf_2

Comment: Ok thank you. I don't anticipate many Bakeries, so I guess if there's no other option ... another way would be to add a points attribute, and add/subtract to it in the controller whenever the pastries are sold and order them from that, but I didn't want to do that because if the Bakery calls to say they're giving me 100 more pastries to boost their rating, i wanted to just add it in the form field and have it all be done automatically, instead of having to calculate and adjust all the points etc.

Comment: ```@sorted_bakeries = all_specified_bakeries.sort_by { |br| Bakery.br_point_count(br) }``` is giving me ```TypeError: String can't be coerced into Integer
 from app/models/bakery.rb:420:in `+'
 from app/models/bakery.rb:420:in `br_point_count'
 from (irb):15:in `block in irb_binding'
 from (irb):15:in `sort_by'
 from (irb):15``` while the function works find on its own

Comment: there is something error on your `br_point_count` method, you need to `to_i` before do sum